# How can I solve this integral for a MGF?

Tags: calculus, probability, integration

To calculate the joint MGF of a function, I need to calculate this integral:
$$M_{XY}(t_1,t_2)=\int_{0}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(e^{t_1x+t_2y})\left({{e^{-y}}\over\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-{1\over2}(x-y)^2}\right)dxdy$$
And I wonder if this is correct:
$$M_{XY}(t_1,t_2)=\int_0^\infty e^{t_2y-y}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{t_1x}\cdot\frac{e^{-\frac{(x-y)^2}{2}}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}dxdy$$

Is it correct to replace
$\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{t_1x}\cdot\frac{e^{-\frac{(x-y)^2}{2}}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}dx$ with the moment generating function of a Normal distribution with mean $y$ and variance $1$, or how do you solve this integral?

*The joint density function given is $\displaystyle f(x,y)=\left({{e^{-y}}\over\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-{1\over2}(x-y)^2}\right); -\infty<x<\infty, 0<y<\infty.$

Comment: Yes you can replace it. If you would evaluate that integral, you would just compute again the mgf of a normally distributed random variable.

Answer (score 1):

What you mentioned is correct, and note that
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{t_1x}\cdot\frac{e^{-\frac{(x-y)^2}{2}}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\;dx= e^{t_1y+\frac{1}{2}t_1^2}$$
as being the MGF of a normal distribution with mean $y$ and variance $1$.

Then,
$$M_{XY}(t_1,t_2)=e^{\frac{1}{2}t_1^2}\int_0^\infty e^{y(t_1+t_2-1)} \;dy=\frac{e^{\frac{1}{2}t_1^2}}{1-t_1-t_2},$$
provided that $t_1+t_2<1.$ Otherwise, $M_{XY}(t_1,t_2)=\infty$.